# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in python

Tags: python, confluence

I'm developing a confluence RPA using Python.
Even if the exact variable is put in the method, errors continue.

Here is my Code.

**CODE :**

```
from atlassian import Conflunce

confluence=Confluence(
   url='My Company url',
   username='Company username',
   password='Company password')

space = confluence.get_page_by_title("TEST","TEST1",0,100,None)
print(space)
```

**RESULT :**

```
 get_page_by_title return response.get("results")[0]

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: @Passerby I just modified the code.

Comment: That's not your code though is it? I suggest you copy/paste the real code ensuring that the relevant fragment that's inducing the error is included

Comment: You're missing the `response` variable declaration. Attach the important part of the code.